# Show specific 1 value from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this function written in python. I want this thing show only one value.

Here's the code

```py
def show_data():
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(myresult, columns=['Year', 'Production (Ton)'])
    df['Max Prod'] = df['Production (Ton)'].max())

    print(df)
```

And of course the output is this

```
    Year Production (Ton)  Max Prod

0   2010           339491    366999
1   2011           366999    366999
2   2012           361986    366999
3   2013           329461    366999
4   2014           355464    366999
5   2015           344998    366999
6   2016           274317    366999
7   2017           200916    366999
8   2018           217246    366999
9   2019           119830    366999
10  2020            66640    366999
```

Since it has the same value, I want the output like this

```
    Year Production (Ton)  Max Prod

0   2010           339491    366999    
1   2011           366999    
2   2012           361986   
3   2013           329461   
4   2014           355464  
5   2015           344998   
6   2016           274317   
7   2017           200916   
8   2018           217246  
9   2019           119830   
10  2020            66640
```

What should I change or add to my code?

Comment: You must fill the rest with something. do you want to fill them with NA or empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shift` to generate a mask that can be used to replace duplicate consecutive values:

```
df.loc[df['Max Prod'] == df['Max Prod'].shift(1), 'Max Prod'] = ''
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Year  Production (Ton) Max Prod
0   2010            339491   366999
1   2011            366999 
2   2012            361986 
3   2013            329461 
4   2014            355464 
5   2015            344998 
6   2016            274317 
7   2017            200916 
8   2018            217246 
9   2019            119830 
10  2020             66640
```

Comment: What if I add another column like 'Min Prod' and the output is min value production. Should I add the code one by one or there's another optimized solution?

Comment: @twyla Good question! In this case, yes, just copy the code. There isn't really a more concise solution for 2 columns. If you have bunch more, you can use a loop, but for just 2 it's probably not really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have the function as:

```
def show_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(myresult, columns=['Year', 'Production (Ton)'])
    df['Max Prod'] = ''
    df.iloc[0, -1] = df['Production (Ton)'].max()

    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have now:

```
def show_data():    
    df = pd.DataFrame(myresult, columns=['Year', 'Production (Ton)'])
    df['Max Prod'] = df['Production (Ton)'].max())
    df = df['Max Prod'].drop_duplicates()
    df = df.fillna('')
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Year  Production-(Ton) Max Prod
0   2010            339491   549713
1   2011            366999 
2   2012            361986 
3   2013            329461 
4   2014            355464 
5   2015            344998 
6   2016            274317 
7   2017            200916 
8   2018            217246 
9   2019            119830 
10  2020             66640
```